# OLEDDB and web server

Tags: asp.net, webforms, oledb

Okay, I have a problem with OLEDB. I have install the "AccessDataBaseEngine.exe" and I am able to upload an Excel file to a Gridview on my local server. When I try to upload on my online web application (With Windows Azure) I get the following error: "**The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.1.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.**" It does not make any sense to me as to why it does not work and after searching the web everyone suggests to install the AccessDataBaseEngine 2007 (which i did) and as mentioned above it works only on the local server. Anyone knows how to resolve this?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What is the bitness of your local machine vs the remote machine? I take it you are saying it works on your workstation but not on the server?